# How to style individual cells using 'cellsRenderer' in jQWidgets?

Tags: javascript, jqwidget

If I’m passing a string, and that string is empty, I’m using cellsRenderer to return the string ***–Unspecified–***. However, the returned string is at the **top left** of the cell and not vertically centered as are all the rest of cells.

[image: Image of jQWidgets table]

Why doesn’t this happen naturally? What do I need to do to keep everything uniform?

Here’s the affected snippet where I’m using `cellsRenderer`:

```
    cellsRenderer: function (row, column, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
      if (value == "") {
        return `<i>--Unspecified--</i>`;            
      }
    }
```

Example Table:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var data = [
    {
      id: "1",
      legalName: "Agrawal, Parag",
      agencyName: "Social Services",
      agencyAddress:
        "Market Square, 1355 Market St<br>#900<br>San Francisco, CA 94103",
      phone: "(415) 222-9670",
      hireDate: "04-3-2022",
      dob: "08-09-2000",
      has401k: true
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Zuckerberg, Mark",
      agencyName: "Defense Advocates Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 456-1234",
      hireDate: "01-30-2019",
      dob: "",
      has401k: true
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Walker, Johnny",
      agencyName: "Prosecutor's Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 329-0124",
      hireDate: "10-03-2016",
      dob: "03-01-1988",
      has401k: false
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Daniels, Jack",
      agencyName: "Prosecutor's Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 856-5309",
      hireDate: "07-28-2011",
      dob: "",
      has401k: false
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Fonda, Jane",
      agencyName: "Social Services",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 456-1234",
      hireDate: "06-14-2021",
      dob: "04-28-1979",
      has401k: true
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Bauer, Jack",
      agencyName: "National Defense",
      agencyAddress: "24 Bauer Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 242-4242",
      hireDate: "11-10-2008",
      dob: "11-13-1975",
      has401k: false
    }
  ];
  // prepare the data
  var source = {
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
      { name: "legalName" },
      { name: "agencyName" },
      { name: "agencyAddress" },
      { name: "phone" },
      { name: "hireDate", type: "date" },
      { name: "dob", type: "date" },
      { name: "has401k", type: "bool" }
    ],
    localdata: data
  };
  var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
  var source = {
    localdata: data,
    datatype: "array",
    loadComplete: function (data) {},
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {}
  };

  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
    source: dataAdapter,
    sortable: true,
    theme: "energyblue",
    width: "98%",
    height: "630px",
    pageable: false,
    columnsresize: true,
    selectionMode: "none",
    filterable: true,
    showfilterrow: true,
    autoheight: true,
    autorowheight: true,
    groupable: true,
    columns: [
      { text: "Legal Name", datafield: "legalName", width: "15%" },
      {
        text: "Agency Name",
        datafield: "agencyName",
        filtertype: "checkedlist",
        width: "20%"
      },
      { text: "Agency Address", datafield: "agencyAddress", width: "20%" },
      { text: "Phone", datafield: "phone", width: "15%" },
      {
        text: "Hire Date",
        datafield: "hireDate",
        cellsformat: "d",
        filtertype: "range",
        width: "10%"
      },
      {
        text: "DOB",
        datafield: "dob",
        cellsformat: "d",
        filtertype: "range",
        width: "10%",
        cellsRenderer: function (row, column, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
          if (value == "") {
            return `<i>--Unspecified--</i>`;            
          }
        }        
      },
      {
        text: "Has 401K",
        datafield: "has401k",
        width: "10%",
        columntype: "checkbox",
        filtertype: "checkedlist"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.auto-margin {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 8vh;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  background-color: #aaa;
  
  code {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

#jqxgrid {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.notice {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>

<div id="jqxWidget">
  <header>
    <h2 class="text-center">Example: How to style individual cells using <code>cellrenderer</code></h2>
  </header>
  <div id="jqxgrid" class="auto-margin"></div>
</div>
<p class="notice"><strong>*All data is test data only.</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm still in time to lend you a hand.

The return ***value*** in **cellsRenderer**() will be used directly to render the UI just like the jquery **html()** >> $('#container').**html**('*<div style="color:red;">content</div>*') did. Therefore you need to return a styled HTML syntax.

To retain all original styling, you can re-use back the argument ***defaulthtml*** in **cellsRenderer**() as that is the default HTML syntax which will be used to render the UI and it consists all styling within it as well.

You can try replace your return ***value*** in **cellsRenderer**() with the '*defaulthtml*' but changing its original content as shown below :

```
// return `<i>--Unspecified--</i>`;
return $(defaulthtml).html(`<i>--Unspecified--</i>`)[0].outerHTML;
```

I had updated your snippet and you can see the result.

Hope it helps !

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var data = [
    {
      id: "1",
      legalName: "Agrawal, Parag",
      agencyName: "Social Services",
      agencyAddress:
        "Market Square, 1355 Market St<br>#900<br>San Francisco, CA 94103",
      phone: "(415) 222-9670",
      hireDate: "04-3-2022",
      dob: "08-09-2000",
      has401k: true
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Zuckerberg, Mark",
      agencyName: "Defense Advocates Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 456-1234",
      hireDate: "01-30-2019",
      dob: "",
      has401k: true
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Walker, Johnny",
      agencyName: "Prosecutor's Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 329-0124",
      hireDate: "10-03-2016",
      dob: "03-01-1988",
      has401k: false
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Daniels, Jack",
      agencyName: "Prosecutor's Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 856-5309",
      hireDate: "07-28-2011",
      dob: "",
      has401k: false
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Fonda, Jane",
      agencyName: "Social Services",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 456-1234",
      hireDate: "06-14-2021",
      dob: "04-28-1979",
      has401k: true
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Bauer, Jack",
      agencyName: "National Defense",
      agencyAddress: "24 Bauer Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 242-4242",
      hireDate: "11-10-2008",
      dob: "11-13-1975",
      has401k: false
    }
  ];
  // prepare the data
  var source = {
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
      { name: "legalName" },
      { name: "agencyName" },
      { name: "agencyAddress" },
      { name: "phone" },
      { name: "hireDate", type: "date" },
      { name: "dob", type: "date" },
      { name: "has401k", type: "bool" }
    ],
    localdata: data
  };
  var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
  var source = {
    localdata: data,
    datatype: "array",
    loadComplete: function (data) {},
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {}
  };

  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
    source: dataAdapter,
    sortable: true,
    theme: "energyblue",
    width: "98%",
    height: "630px",
    pageable: false,
    columnsresize: true,
    selectionMode: "none",
    filterable: true,
    showfilterrow: true,
    autoheight: true,
    autorowheight: true,
    groupable: true,
    columns: [
      { text: "Legal Name", datafield: "legalName", width: "15%" },
      {
        text: "Agency Name",
        datafield: "agencyName",
        filtertype: "checkedlist",
        width: "20%"
      },
      { text: "Agency Address", datafield: "agencyAddress", width: "20%" },
      { text: "Phone", datafield: "phone", width: "15%" },
      {
        text: "Hire Date",
        datafield: "hireDate",
        cellsformat: "d",
        filtertype: "range",
        width: "10%"
      },
      {
        text: "DOB",
        datafield: "dob",
        cellsformat: "d",
        filtertype: "range",
        width: "10%",
        cellsRenderer: function (row, column, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
          if (value == "") {
            // return `<i>--Unspecified--</i>`;
            return $(defaulthtml).html(`<i>--Unspecified--</i>`)[0].outerHTML;
          }
        }        
      },
      {
        text: "Has 401K",
        datafield: "has401k",
        width: "10%",
        columntype: "checkbox",
        filtertype: "checkedlist"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.auto-margin {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 8vh;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  background-color: #aaa;
  
  code {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

#jqxgrid {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.notice {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>

<div id="jqxWidget">
  <header>
    <h2 class="text-center">Example: How to style individual cells using <code>cellrenderer</code></h2>
  </header>
  <div id="jqxgrid" class="auto-margin"></div>
</div>
<p class="notice"><strong>*All data is test data only.</strong></p>
```